# Not able to connect to Google Cloud SQL with Slim framework on Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, slim

I'm using Slim framework to build api for my application. I'm not able to connect to Google Cloud SQL.

I have provided the error message below.

I have been using this in codeigniter without any problem. Can someone help me understand on how to fix this issue.

DB Code:

```
function getDB() {

$dbhost=":/cloudsql/projid:instancename";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="dbname";

$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass); 
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $dbConnection;
}
```

Error message

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed. errno=0}}
```

P.S. I'm not facing this issue on Localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `PDO` connection string should be using `mysql:unix_socket` instead of `mysql:host`.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/cloud-sql/

**PDO_MySQL**

```
$db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>;dbname=<database-name>',
  'root',  // username
  ''       // password
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I changed my code

From

```
function getDB() {

$dbhost=":/cloudsql/projid:instancename";
$dbuser="root"; 
$dbpass="";
$dbname="dbname";

$dbConnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass); 
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $dbConnection;
}
```

To

```
function getDB() {

    $dbConnection = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/<your-project-id>:<your-instance-name>;dbname=<database-name>',
  'root',  // username
  ''       // password
  );
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $dbConnection;
    }
```

Comment: Great to see you got it sorted!